# What's the latest on JavaFX and mobile phones?

Tags: mobile, javafx

What's the latest on JavaFX mobile? I'm having trouble finding any relatively current info regarding what phones (if any..?) are JFX compatible, how to distribute applications to said phones, etc. I have a current desktop application, and another semi-related mobile project is on the horizon (within the next couple months). If I can use JavaFX with minimal pains, that'd be fantastic (to minimize the number of different technologies). My gut says Android or another mobile OS/framework/technology would be the better choice at the moment...

Still trying to wrap my head around the current "reach" of JavaFX. In theory it all sounds fantastic (deskop, mobile, web, blu-ray applications in one go), but it seems to be a ways out from truly being that.

My developing experience has been pleasant so far with JavaFX if it's any consolation... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fan of JavaFX myself, I was hoping that this years JavaOne (2010) will shed some light on the topic.

Best case scenario for us developers...Larry E convinces Steve J to allow for a JRE on the IPhone.

Worst case scenario for us developers...JavaFX continues its current trajectory toward oblivion.

Comment: *sigh* If only we could all play nice together. We can hope... though I can't help but think Java and Jobs are two J's that just won't jive ;). Thanks for the response, Eric.

Comment: double sigh because I pretty much agree... I was super excited last year about JavaFX (javafx everywhere....tv/phone/desktop)and even deployed a javafx app to the Java Store http://www.java.com/en/store/index.jsp (still in beta) but unfortunately the momentum is just not there. Cheers to hoping Oracle has an ace in the hole.